# How to return value from suspend function without blocking thread

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

I have a suspend method: checkIfAvailable() that returns a Boolean. I want to get that boolean value and then use it in my activity. I try this the following way(not sure if this is how it should be done):

```
suspend fun checkIfAvailable(year: Int): Boolean = viewModelScope.async{
        return@async dao.checkIfAvailable(year)
    }.await()
```

This returns a boolean. The problem is that i can't use that boolean, because the function must be a suspend function as await() must be called inside one.

How do i get the boolean value **without blocking the main thread**?

I tried it with runBlocking in my activity:

```
fun something(tag: Int): Boolean {
            return runBlocking {
            return@runBlocking checkIfAvailable(tag)
        }
}
```

but this crashes or blocks the mainthread.

I just need a way to get the value out of the suspend function and into a variable without blocking the thread.

Comment: It is not possible. You can't make a blocking (i.e. time-consuming) task magically return a result immediately. You must put your code that reacts to the result of this check in the coroutine.

Comment: why not use `LiveData` object if you are using `ViewModel`, that way you'll be properly notified of a new change when observing that particular livedata (`Boolean` in this case)

Comment: What is `@async`?

Comment: the @async after the return statment means, that you don't want to return out of the function, but the inner anonymous async function of the viewmodelscope.

functionOuter {
    innerAsyncFunction{
       somethiung
       return@async
    }
}
Here return@async returns only out of the innerAsyncFunction, not out of the whole functionOuter

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside your activity:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
      val result = checkIfAvailable(year)
}
```